# Wrong locale in SQL Query results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server 2005 database set to locale Turkish_CI_AS. The locale setting of the pc of the SQL Server is set to Turkish. Turkish decimal separator is "," and thousands separator is ".". There is a field with datatype decimal(14, 3) and it has a record with value "400,123" (that's four hundred). When I use Open Table in SQL Manager the value is correct in the result grid. But when I query the table in SQL query window the result value is "400.123" which is wrong. I also get this wrong result in my Linq query results. What should I do to get the correct value?

Answer (score 0):

Try altering the table column  to specife collation_name 
like Alter column myNogoodColation Collate Turkish_BIN

look here for help: [ms-help://MS.SQLCC.v9/MS.SQLSVR.v9.en/tsqlref9/html/56483d24-add7-483d-9b96-c6fda460ddbc.htm](http://ms-help://MS.SQLCC.v9/MS.SQLSVR.v9.en/tsqlref9/html/56483d24-add7-483d-9b96-c6fda460ddbc.htm)

COLLATE {  | database_default }
 :: = 
     { Windows_collation_name } | { SQL_collation_name }

Comment: It seems you can't use BIN collation with data type decimal: Expression type decimal is invalid for COLLATE clause.

Answer (score 0):

What is default language of the login that you are using?
You can check it by selecting sys.server_principals, or ask DBA if you don't have rights to see the login in that view
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx

Comment: I checked it, it is set as "us_english". Also SELECT @@language says "us_english" (are these related?).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I ever got out of this spot was to convert the decimal to a string, replace the dot with nothing (aka empty string) and then the comma with a dot.
As in

```
Replace(Replace(Cast(<value> as varchar(14)), '.', ''), ',', '.')
```

Not elegant but helps to convert from Excel to SQL server where I encountered the problem so far.